# Python - Using 'with lock threading' takes 1.5 seconds for each thread to run

Tags: python, multithreading, optimization, thread-safety

So I am trying to send discord notification to different webhooks and my idea is to send it ASAP to different webhooks with so less second between each other. Right now it is between 1,5 - 2 sec between each notification and I wonder how I can optimze it to even better than that.

I started to use thread for each sending notification but I used `with lock` function to make it run one and one so the console would not spam and also make it thread-safe incase of threading goes by mistakes.

What I have done is:

```
def sendData(webhook, data):
    with lock:
        while True:
            try:
                response = requests.post(webhook, data=json.dumps(data), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})

                if response.status_code == 200:
                    logger.success('Sent to Discord')
                    logger.success(datetime.utcnow().strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3])
                    break

                elif response.status_code == 429:
                    sleep_time = int(response.headers['retry-after']) / 1000
                    logger.status('Rate limited! Please wait ' + str(sleep_time) + ' seconds')
                    time.sleep(sleep_time)

                else:
                    raise ValueError(
                        'Request to slack returned an error %s, the response is:\n%s' % (
                            response.status_code, response.text))

            except HTTPError as err:
                randomtime = random.randint(0, 1)
                logger.error('Retrying in {} secs'.format(randomtime))
                time.sleep(randomtime)
                continue
```

and my question is how I can speed up the time between each sending without causing any threading-issues ?

EDIT:

So basically if I removed `with lock` this would happend to my console:

[image: Pic 1]

As you can see it is all messy because the threads are running quite fast and I assume they collisions with each other and it would gave me also a lot of rate limit because of its sending so fast and basically will not wait until its done since the rest of the other threadings are going to run all the time.

With lock this is how it looks now:

[image: Pic2]

and as you can see it looks a lot better bt not I dont have the milliseconds on but it can sometimes be between 1.5 - 2 sec for each one to send to discord.

Comment: I don't understand this. Why do you need the lock? I don't see any shared resources in your code that would require it. And why do you implement concurrency when you actually want your code to run sequentially? This even bears the risk of one thread infinitely blocking all of your notifications when it's target starts raising `HTTPError` for whatever reason.

Comment: Hello @shmee - I have no edited the code with pictures that might be better to see. There could happend that I might not was supposed to run `with lock` at first place and that could be wrong However when running sequentially it caused me what happend in picture 1. Which I didn't wished too. Maybe you have any better solution and also about the shared resources. I dont quite get it what you mean by that?

Comment: No, picture 1 shows concurrent execution. Sequential execution is what makes your output look like pic 2. But If you want it sequentially, I don't see the point of using threads at all. Why don't you just call your `sendData` function sequentially in a loop over a collection of whatever `webhook` or `data` is? A shared resource would be for example a common list, that all threads pop elements from. There you need a lock around `list.pop()` to make it thread-safe. Unless `logger` is just a wrapper around `print()`, you don't do anything like that.

Comment: As for the 1.5-2 sec delays .. it would be interesting to see where that comes from. I somewhat suspect that coming from the `requests.post()` and being due to delayed responses from certain webhooks. In that case the source is outside the reach of your code and there's hardly anything you can do about that.

Comment: @shmee It could very well the requests now that I think of it actually. I did use the webhook-data before and it took also longer time. If there was a way that I could actually make a sort of timer for the reuqests time to send that would solve it actually. It would be totally understandable if it was the cause maybe?
About the logger. It is just a print and what multiprocessing process it is using and nothing else.

Comment: Since `requests.post()` is just a wrapper around `requests.request()` you could use [timeouts](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#timeouts) to limit the time spent attempting to connect and waiting for a response.